# Why is it 64 virtual processors within four sockets, a quad core CPU?

Tags: cpu

According to [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](http://futuretech.blinkenlights.nl/misc/cpumemory.pdf):

> the “standard building blocks” for most
>   data centers will be a computer with up to four sockets,
>   each filled with a quad core CPU that, in the case of Intel
>   CPUs, will be hyper-threaded.This means the standard
>   system in the data center will have up to 64 virtual processors.

In my opinion, it will have up to 4*4*2 = 32 virtual processors. Why is it 64?

Comment: Perhaps two "computers" (two "standard building blocks") per "standard system" or perhaps a mistake in the article?

Comment: Well, Xeon phi can have 4 threads, but I admit that's straining it a bit. Probably just a mistake.